# How can I have different footnote separators in one word page?

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I want to have two different footnote separators in one page, for example, one kind of separator is [1], [2]... and another one is (1), (2)...
when I translate some documents with footnotes, I want to have my own footnotes in the same page and hope they can differ from the original ones.
I know I can do it in manual way, but still wonder if there is an easier method.
Thanks in advance~

Comment: Have you tried setting up two footnote styles?

Answer (score 0):

This is a much more complicated question than it appears, because references
have two parts: One in the main text and one in the footnote text.

Unfortunately, I don't think that there is any automatic way of doing it,
so it has to be done manually. It is better done when the document is finished,
as it is quite awkward to do.

To add square brackets around references in the Main text :

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to display the Replace tab of the Find and Replace dialog box.
- In "Find What" enter `^f` (use a lowercase letter "f")
- In "Replace With" enter `[^&]`
- If you would like to also change the font or other attributes,
  click *More* and then *Format > Font*, while the cursor is still in the
  "Replace With" field.
- Click on Replace All to do all footnotes.
  For selectively replacing only some footnotes, click *Find Next* and *Replace*
  for replacing one-by-one.

Do not repeat this action, or some footnotes will end up with too many brackets.

[image]